# Validity of *(ptra + 0).prop and (*(ptra + 0)).prop

Tags: c++

Why is  `*(ptra + 0).prop` not valid and `(*(ptra + 0)).prop` valid ? . I know that left side of the dot operator must have a structure. But I am still confused. Could someone explain to me the difference between the two ?

```
class myobj 
{
public:
    int v;
};

int main()
{

    myobj *ptra = new myobj[2]();

    *(ptra + 0).v = 12 //Error

    (*(ptra + 0)).v = 12 ; //OK

    return 0;

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because `operator .` has a [higher precedence](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence) then `operator *` , so

```
*(ptra + 0).v
```

means

```
*((ptr + 0).v)
```

and not

```
(*(ptra + 0)).v
```

`*((ptr + 0).v)` here is incorrect syntax, because `(ptr + 0)` is not a class or union, so has no any members.

Comment: Okay so operator precedence does make sense here. However I am still confused how because of operator precedence does `*(ptra + 0).v` become `*((ptr + 0).v)
`

Answer (score 0):

Errors like this one are due to **operator precedence**. In this case, the first operator that gets executed is `operator.` and the second that gets executed ins `operator*`. This is why one line compiles and the other doesn't, even if they look very much alike.

To override this operator precedence, you use parenthesis, as in

```
(1 + 2) * 3 = 9
```

as opposed to

```
1 + 2 * 3 = 7.
```